# Unable to get the button of the alert dialog to prevent the dialog from closing in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog

I wanted to create an alert dialog that won't close on hitting its `positiveButton`. I modified my code as per many tutorials I found online. But I am not able to get the button, `builder.getButton`.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
   with(builder) {
        setTitle("Hello....?")
        setCancelable(false)
        setPositiveButton("Done", null)
        setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        show()
        val positiveButton: Button = builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the button on the builder, you need to get it from the dialog (which you create using the builder). Modify your code to:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        with(builder) {
            setTitle("Hello....?")
            setCancelable(false)
            setPositiveButton("Done", null)
            setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            val dialog = this.create()
            dialog.show()
            val positiveButton: Button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
            positiveButton.setOnClickListener {
            }
}
```